# Laravel cerrar sesión por inactividad utilizando Socialize

Tags: laravel

Les dejo una pregunta sobre un proyecto en la cual, estoy queriendo implementar algo dentro de todo sencillo pero que no me está dando bola y no logro darme cuenta por que.

El proyecto está hecho con Laravel 6. Estoy utilizando Socialize para logueo con Google. Lo que quiero resolver es que, al cabo de cierta cantidad de minutos de inactividad, se me cierre la sesión de manera automática.

Busque por todos lados, cambiando el valor del archivo de configuraciones en sessions.php -> 'lifetime', pero no me da mucha bola. Obviamente agregue en mi logueo el Auth::check() para que se implemente, segun lo que vi en la documentación de laravel, pero tampoco tuve resultados.

Espero puedan ayudarme con este pequeño inconveniente. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: A que te refieres con "*no me da mucha bola*"? El lifetime controla el tiempo de sesion, no te funciono? Por otro lado, tu problema es que se cierra la sesion, bien, ahora que solucion quieres? Que se mantenga? Que se reestablezca? Que te avise que se va a cerrar la sesion?

Comment: Perdón, me refiero a que no responde laravel correctamente a los cambios que yo le implemento. Lo que quiero lograr es que, al cabo de 20 minutos de inactividad, se cierre la sesión. He implementado las cosas que mencione en la pregunta pero no tengo respuesta por parte de laravel en base a funcionamiento. Entiendo que esto es porque al manejar la sesión con Socialize, entrando con Google, no disponemos del token nativo de sesión de laravel y por eso no detecta el tiempo para luego desloguear.

Comment: @Daptee lo lograstes solucionar?